# 1 minute deployment of custom Linux installation

Tags: linux

A typical Debian/Ubuntu installation takes at least 15 minutes, and you have to answer a lot of questions along the way. Yet a VPS service on the Web is able to deploy a ready-to-use Linux server in under 1 minute.

I'd like to have my own prepared image file with pre-installed packages that I can plug straight into VirtualBox, or upload to a hosting service, and -bang- there it is, without the 15 minute manual installation or answering any questions. It's just ready in as little time as possible (like a minute or so).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: 1) Install Linux exactly the way you want it. 2) Take a snapshot of the installation.

Comment: Which are good tools for taking snapshots?

Comment: Each virtual machine system has its own method. Sometimes, you can just copy the machine files.

Comment: VirtualBox supports states of a given virtual machine. You can also simply save the virtual hdd and duplicate and changing the uid as required.

Comment: Can I upload this virtual machine image to a hosting service, and it will instantly launch? Or do they only take installation .iso files?

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat provides a tool for automating installs in the form of [Kickstart](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html). It allows system administrators to roll out multiple standard installs. While developed originally by Red Hat (and therefore also available on it's clones like [Centos](http://www.centos.org/) and [Scientific Linux](https://www.scientificlinux.org/) and is also available on [Fedora](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html)) it is also used to a lesser extent by some other distributions.